# Can Wingardium Leviosa be used as a weapon?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, magical-theory

Can Wingardium Leviosa be used as a weapon, like throwing chairs or something at people?

Comment: Yes, it can; https://youtu.be/rgyitSlMtMY?t=229

Comment: I'd say you'd be hardpressed to think up a scenario where being able to generate force to an object couldn't be used as a weapon when applied in the proper circumstances, unless the amount of force were so weak, it could not do any bodily harm to a person.

Answer (score 15):

## Yes, it can be used in an attack.

Wingardium Leviosa can indeed be used to levitate items to use as weapons. Ron used it to levitate the troll’s club and whack it on the head.

> “Hermione had sunk to the floor in fright; Ron pulled out his own wand – not knowing what he was going to do he heard himself cry the first spell that came into his head: *‘Wingardium Leviosa!’*
>
> The club flew suddenly out of the troll’s hand, rose high, high up into the air, turned slowly over – and dropped, with a sickening crack, on to its owner’s head.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 10 (Hallowe’en)*</sup></sub>

Trelawney used levitation as an attack during the battle at Hogwarts.

> “I have more!’ shrieked Professor Trelawney from over the banisters, ‘more for any who want them! Here –’
> And with a movement like a tennis serve, she heaved another enormous crystal sphere from her bag, waved her wand through the air, and caused the ball to speed across the hall and smash through a window.” 
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 32 (The Elder Wand)*</sup></sub>

So yes, Wingardium Leviosa can be used as a weapon.

Comment: How do you know Trelawney used Wingardium Leviosa specifically? Actually I would say Wingardium Leviosa can not be used to through things **at** people, but rather **on** people like in the case with the troll. Meaning one can use the spell to make an object go up and soar in the air, not fly rapidly any direction you want hitting the aim directly. Remember when Lupin made a gum hit Peeves - he didn't use WL, he needed something else to perform that.